# References to languages lacking morphology in scientific literature

Tags: morphology, linguistic-universals, morphological-typology

Are there any references of natural languages lacking morphology in the *scientific literature*? I suppose there should be, given the topic's importance and the popular opinion on this, but so far all I've found is [this](http://www.thai-language.com/resources/muansuwan-verb-complexes.pdf) (clearly insufficient). This question is related to a [previous one](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28287/languages-w-out-morphology)

Comment: A propos the dissertation, why is it clearly insufficient? I assume you have in mind some kind of refereeing criterion (which you should explain).

Comment: Insufficient because it's the only one

Comment: Some languages usually mentioned as more extreme examples of isolating languages are: Classical Chinese, Vietnamese, Yoruba. But none are totally isolating, all have some words which are not monomorphemic. To find works on this topic search for 'morphological typology'.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut "But none are totally isolating..." -- I'm afraid the jury is still out on this. I'd say compound words are permitted in a totally isolating language if they [compound roots only](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28287/languages-w-out-morphology#comment58911_28287)